# Open source persistent Java cache?

Tags: library, java

I'm looking for an open-source Java library for persistent caching.

I don't need read/write guarantees; I just need the cache to be able to be able to start and stop and keep most cached data. Ideally, it would also not leak disk space.

And old version of Ehcache would fit the bill, but I need a library that is currently maintained. (I don't want to put my users through dependency hell.)